# Javascript Value Check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document.write

I'm writing a script that parses an XML file and displays it in html. Here it is:

```
<script>
$.get("api.xml", function (xml) {
    $(xml).find("row").each(function () {

       var date = $(this).attr('date');
       var amount = $(this).attr('amount');
       var balance = $(this).attr('balance');

document.write("A: " + date + "<br />B: " + amount + " ISK<br />C: " + balance + " ISK<br /><br /><br /><br />");
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to modify the output of "document.write", so that if the value "amount" is positive, enter the word "green", otherwise, if negative, enter the word "red". I tried to write it as follows:

```
<script>
$.get("api.xml", function (xml) {
    $(xml).find("row").each(function () {

       var date = $(this).attr('date');
       var amount = $(this).attr('amount');
       var balance = $(this).attr('balance');

document.write("<script> if (amount >= 0) { document.write("green"); } else{ document.write("red"); } </scri" + "pt>");
    });
});
</script>
```

But in that piece, I get a syntax error in "document.write". What I have written wrong and how could fix it?

Comment: Note that your usage of `document.write` will replace the whole page with the new content.

Comment: SO's syntax highlighter has the answer for you. Its the quotes, see how 'green' and 'red' are highlighted in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can compute the color before writing the output with document.write. 
Something like this should work:

```
<script>
$.get("api.xml", function (xml) {
  $(xml).find("row").each(function () {
    var date = $(this).attr('date');
    var amount = $(this).attr('amount');
    var balance = $(this).attr('balance');

    var color = "green";
    if (amount < 0) {
     color = "red";
    }

    document.write("A: " + date + "<br />B: <span style='color:" + color + "'>" + amount + " ISK</span><br />C: " + balance + " ISK<br /><br /><br /><br />");
 });
});
</script>
```

(syntax unchecked)

Comment: you can write that in just one line: `var color = amount < 0 ? "red" : "green";`

Answer (score 3):

To get an answer just look, how this code is highlighted. The words 'green' and 'red' are outside the quotes. You should use single quotes (or escape the double quotes).

The other question is why do you use metaprogramming for such a simple task. Just write a condition with two different `document.write` statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$.get("api.xml", function (xml) {
    $(xml).find("row").each(function () {

       var date = $(this).attr('date');
       var amount = $(this).attr('amount');
       var balance = $(this).attr('balance');
       document.write(amount >= 0 ? "green" : "red");
    });
});
</script>
```